# Scala higher order function issue

Tags: scala, functional-programming

My aim: To minimize lines of code.

Have a few function like `f1`, `f2` ...

```
f1(A: String)

f2(A: String, B: Long, C: User)
```

Want to process it with high order function approach.

```
def processf1(request: Request[AnyContent], f: (String) => String)

def processf2(request: Request[AnyContent], f: (String, Long, User) => String) = {...}
```

Can I create **ONE** common `process` function for `f1, f2` ?

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could parametrize `processf` types:

```
def processf[S,T](request: Request[S], f: T => String) = ...
```

Examples of use:

```
processf(new Request[Int], (x: String) => x)

processf(new Request[Int], (x: (String, Long, User)) => x._1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer, but not so clear for me, could please clarify

for example 3 function which have duplicate like `RequestUtil.getRequestParams`

```
  private def regUser(request: Request[AnyContent], f: (String) => String): String = {
    RequestUtil.getRequestParams(request, APPConst.USER) match {
      case Some(map) => f(map(APPConst.USER))
      case None => JsonUtil.toJson(APPConst.ERROR -> APPConst.POST_PARAMS_EMPTY_MISMATCH)
    }
  }

  private def regDog(request: Request[AnyContent], f: (Dog, Enum, String, String) => String): String = {
    RequestUtil.getRequestParams(request, APPConst.Dog) match {
      case Some(m) => process(m, f)
      case None => JsonUtil.toJson(APPConst.ERROR -> APPConst.POST_PARAMS_EMPTY_MISMATCH)
    }
  }

  private def regCat[T](request: Request[AnyContent], f: (Cat, Enum) => String): String = {
    RequestUtil.getRequestParams(request, APPConst.CAT) match {
      case Some(map) => process(map, f)
      case None => JsonUtil.toJson(APPConst.ERROR -> APPConst.POST_PARAMS_EMPTY_MISMATCH)
    }
  }
```

and executions

```
 def regUser = Action { request => Ok(views.html.index(regUserProcess(request, UserService.regUser)))}

  def regDog = Action { request => Ok(views.html.index(regCurrProcess(request, UserService.regDog)))}

  def regCat = Action { request => Ok(views.html.index(mainProcess(request, UserService.regCat)))}
```

As you can see 3 different functions with different count parameters `UserService.regUser, UserService.regDog, UserService.regCat` functions

Comment: In Scala you can parametrize functions by type. e.g: `f(x: Int): String = x.toString` and `g(x: Int): x.toString`  can by expressed as an unique function `f[T](x: T): = x.toString`. Thanks to Scala's type inference you can call `f` as `f(1)` and `f("1")`. My answer applies the same strategy but to the function you are passing type.

Comment: In the case of your methods, they could be merged into a type-parametrized single method: `private def regUser[T, S](request: Request[AnyContent], f: T => String, params: S): String = {
  params match {
    case Some(x) => f(x);
    case None => JsonUtil.toJson(APPConst.ERROR -> APPConst.POST_PARAMS_EMPTY_MISMATCH);
  }
}`

Comment: btw, You should't answer your question to add more information. You should edit your original post.